# Using iPad as a shared drawing board in a Skype meeting

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, remote-desktop, software, skype

I use Skype daily for work meetings. My collaborators work in different places around the world and this is the only way to stay connected and work together with them. We are theoretical physicists.

Sometimes, we need to use a drawing board to explain some concept and discuss about mathematics. Does there exist a way to use our iPad Pro as a shared drawing board?

I am looking for a solution which allows me to live share my iPad screen while using Skype on my Mac, so that I can use any drawing app such as Notability. All my collaborators should be able to see what I write during the Skype call.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a solution which allows me to live share my iPad screen while using Skype on my Mac.

Current Skype clients for macOS and iOS doesn't support this feature.

However, if you don't mind using a different app, [Zoom meeting client](https://zoom.us) is the app you are looking for. It includes a plethora of features such as audio, video conferencing, screen sharing with fine grained controls, remote control, shared drawing board, instant messaging etc.

Zoom app has native client app available for all major desktop and mobile operating systems. Zoom has the ability to share the screen of an iPad connected to your Mac. Zoom also comes with its own shared drawing board.

More information about the features can be found by visiting Zoom homepage here:

- [Video Conferencing, Web Conferencing, Webinars, Screen Sharing - Zoom](https://zoom.us)

To learn about the Zoom Whiteboard, visit this link:

- [Share a Whiteboard - Zoom Help Center](https://support.zoom.us/hc/articles/205677665-Share-a-Whiteboard)

---

Zoom is a pretty popular and widely used online meeting app with majority of useful features available in the free plan (The free plan should cover all your requirements). For more details about the features, you can refer to the pricing page here:

- [Plans and Pricing - Zoom](https://zoom.us/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

What you may be able to do in a few months is use the sidecar feature of MacOS Catalina. You can have your iPad be a secondary display, bring up a drawing application on your Mac and then share that screen.

This doesn't help you right now, but will be available in a few months, something like Zoom would definitely be a good option, but it's not always possible to change software

Comment: For the record, Sidecar alone doesn’t solve the problem of allowing other people on the call to share a whiteboard. There’s a plethora of small collaborative drawing apps online though, e.g. draw.chat or aggie.io, you can move its browser window to Sidecar in iPad and distribute a link for collaborative whiteboard experience.

Comment: https://awwapp.com/ and https://liveboard.online/ both offer free tiers and can be used in the fashion you described.